# Is there a simple setting that make Vim find filetype more smart?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Vim does recognize filetype smartly according to the name of the file and the
modeline.

However it cannot deal with this case: I have a file without any special special
suffix, say `somefile`, which is a soft link to a c++ source
file, `somefile.cpp`. Vim seems to only look up the name of `somefile` and think
it is a ordinary text file.

So is it possible to make Vim judge the filetype more reasonably(for instance,
choose the filetype of the filename that contains the suffix) or prompt to let
user choose if it cannot judge in a more complicated case?

Comment: is this for syntax highlighting? you can manually set syntax highlighting to C using `:set syn=c`

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, I need the syntax highlight. And I would not bother to manually set syntax when I open a file. I am just seeking a general way to handle this problem.

Comment: Only other option I can think of is a tweak of @Jeff 's, map it to a hotkey.   As a quicker method, anyway.

Comment: @HongxuChen I edited my answer to provide a permanent solution

Comment: An alternative is the method described in `:h new-filetype-scripts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick Fix

If you are opening a file for the first type, type

> :set syn=c

or some other filetype in place of `c` to change the syntax highlighting.

If this is a file you edit often, you can add a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) to the top of your file.

> /* vim:syntax=c filetype=c */

Any comment type should work for other filetypes, e.g.

> # vim:syntax=python filetype=python

## Permanent Solution

Add this line to your `.vimrc` file:

> au BufNewFile,BufReadPre * if &syntax == '' | silent! execute (':set filetype='.matchstr(resolve(@%),'.[^.]*$')[1:]) | endif

Now, any time you open a file without an extension, it will attempt to see if it is a symbolic link and retrieve the target file. If it is in fact a symbolic link, it will set the syntax to the target file's filetype. Otherwise, it does nothing.

Comment: Generally it's not necessary to set the '`syntax`' option if you set the '`filetype`' option.

Comment: @Heptite i figured as much, but provided it just in case there is some exception that i am unaware of

Comment: There is, but it would be very unusual for a user to encounter that in a normal configuration.

Comment: @Jeff Seems that syntax is set to target file name other than the syntax type(in this case, `syntax=somefile.cpp`, not `syntax=cpp`)?

Comment: @HongxuChen yes, and it works just fine.

Comment: @Jeff unfortunately it does not work for me. Since I know quite little about VimL, would you please give me some advice to get the filetype string in the script above(I know I could use `&filetype` inside a file, but don't know how to get it with a special file,for instance _somefile.cpp_)? Thanks.

Comment: @HongxuChen I am actually just learning vimL, but the script above works for me. Are you 100% sure this is your problem? open you soft-link and type `:set syn=anything.cpp` and see if that works. If it does, try `:echo resolve(@%)` and let me know what you get.

Comment: @Jeff the result of `:echo resolve(@%)` is right, for soft links with both relative and absolute paths, and `:set syn?` exactly returns the file name(actually it is the path). But it still doesn't take effect. The vim is a debian package: `vim-gtk` on a Ubuntu12.04 32b machine, with the version number _2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2_, thanks.

Comment: @HongxuChen hmm... this sort of does what you're asking, but unfortunately now it will break syntax highlighting on some files like .vimrc. i'll see if i can find a better solution. `au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | try | execute (':set filetype='.get(split(matchstr(resolve(@%),'\.[^.]*$'),'\.'), 0)) | catch | | endtry |  endif`

Comment: @Jeff, still not work, and the filetype is like **before**:`conf`, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @HongxuChen sorry, i don't know what to try next. if i can't diagnose/reproduce the error it's hard to troubleshoot!

Comment: @Jeff I understand; and I even guess that it might be some plugin I used that lead to this behavior, and it should cost me a lot of time to locate it. Whenever I find the root cause, I would tell you what I am going wrong. Anyway, thanks for your time and kindness.